# Android Studio: Specify location of gradle or android eclipse project

Tags: java, android, achartengine

I extracted all the files from the achartengine library to the following path:

```
C:\Users\student\Desktop\achartengine-1.2.0\
```

But when I select the path in adding a new module, an error pops up, stating:

```
Specify location of Gradle or Android Eclipse Project
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I had to move to the `jar` files into the `libs` folder.

Comment: what about tar files

Comment: Can anyone pls explain what this means? Thanks!